# Can I just use the following notation when proving a set is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

If given all functions of form $$f(x) = a + b \cos(x) + c \sin(x),$$ where $a,b,c$ are real numbers, would it be sufficient to use the notation "$f(x)$," when proving that the axioms hold and that above is a vector space (i.e. set of all functions of shape $f(x)$)? Another question is: is the following argument how it should be "worded"?

For example, if I wanted to show that $(f+g) = (g+f)$, would it then be sufficient to say that $(f+g)$ has the value $f(x) + g(x)$, which, seeing that $f(x) + g(x)$ are two real numbers, the commutative axiom holds, and we get $g(x) + f(x)$, precisely the value of $(g+f)$, all this done without ever writing the actual shape of the function?

Answer (score 1):

Part of proving that a set is a vector space is proving that the addition operation is closed. In your case this means your proof will need some words like this: "Assuming $f,g$ are each in (THE SET), we must prove that $f+g$ is in (THE SET)". To prove this, I don't see much choice other than having further words like this: "Choose $a,b,c,p,q,r$ such that $f(x) = a + b \cos(x) + c \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = p + q \cos(x) + r \sin(x)$". In other words, you will have to write the actual shape of the function for proving that addition is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can proceed like this. Or, which is basically the same thing, you can say that the set in question is a subset of the space all real functions for which you might know already that it is a vector-space.

You would however still have to make sure that this sets is closed under the two operations addtion and scalar multiplication. Either way, you should not forget to check this.